# What does "don't do yourself wrong" means?

Tags: meaning

I heard this sentence in a song, here's the part:

> People hold on
>
> Don't do yourself wrong
>
> People hold on
>
> We've got to be strong

I'm not sure about the meaning of the sentence "don't do yourself wrong". Can I rephrase it "don't do anything that can make you the bad guy"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slang. "Don't do yourself wrong" means "don't treat yourself badly".

The more commonly heard form is "he did her wrong", most often meaning that he was mean to her, cheated her, was unfaithful to her, or some combination of these.

(The phrase could be unwound into "don't do wrong unto yourself", where "wrong" means "things that are wrong", just as "evil" can be used to mean "things that are evil.")

Answer (score 2):

No.

This phrase isn't referring to doing things that make you the bad guy, it refers to doing things that... "Sell yourself short" is a common phrase, but not very descriptive.

It means don't do things that harm yourself - usually in the form of long term prospects in favor of short term satisfaction. Dropping out of school because it is tough is a common example. While it may make you happy, you are "doing yourself wrong" by limiting your future prospects.

Answer (score -1):

Crudely put, it means "Don't screw yourself."